# ML.NET Binary Classification Model Not Working

Tags: c#, ml.net

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on ML.Net as it appears to be relatively new. I've been running into problem after problem trying to learn how to use it, and I finally figured out it enough to get it to at least run without experiencing an error; however, there seems to be a problem with my model. It always returns 0 with a probability of 50%. I've included my code below. Does anyone know any good resources for the most recent version of ML.Net that I can explore? The code below is supposed to be making a binary classification model that can predict whether a team is going or not going to the playoff. The data is just the final results of last season with most of the data removed so the only columns that remain are the average age, wins, losses, and playoff status (1 = playoffs & 0 = no playoff).

*Program.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data;

namespace MachineLearning2
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string _trainDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "trainingNHL.txt");
        static readonly string _testDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "testingNHL.txt");
        static readonly string _modelPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Model.zip");
        static TextLoader _textLoader;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
            _textLoader = mlContext.Data.TextReader(new TextLoader.Arguments()
            {
                Separator = ",",
                HasHeader = false,
                Column = new[]
                    {
                        new TextLoader.Column("Age", DataKind.R4, 0),
                        new TextLoader.Column("Wins", DataKind.R4, 1),
                        new TextLoader.Column("Losses", DataKind.R4, 2),
                        new TextLoader.Column("Label", DataKind.R4, 3)
                    }
            });
            var model = Train(mlContext, _trainDataPath);
            Evaluate(mlContext, model);
            Predict(mlContext, model);
            PredictWithModelLoadedFromFile(mlContext);

        }

        public static ITransformer Train(MLContext mlContext, string dataPath)
        {
            IDataView dataView = _textLoader.Read(dataPath);
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features","Age", "Wins", "Losses")
                .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(numLeaves: 50, numTrees: 50, minDatapointsInLeafs: 20));
            Console.WriteLine("=============== Create and Train the Model ===============");
            var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);
            Console.WriteLine("=============== End of training ===============");
            Console.WriteLine();
            return model;
        }

        public static void Evaluate(MLContext mlContext, ITransformer model)
        {
            IDataView dataView = _textLoader.Read(_testDataPath);
            Console.WriteLine("=============== Evaluating Model accuracy with Test data===============");
            var predictions = model.Transform(dataView);
            var metrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(predictions, "Label");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Model quality metrics evaluation");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"Accuracy: {metrics.Accuracy:P2}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Auc: {metrics.Auc:P2}");
            Console.WriteLine($"F1Score: {metrics.F1Score:P2}");
            Console.WriteLine("=============== End of model evaluation ===============");
            SaveModelAsFile(mlContext, model);
        }

        private static void SaveModelAsFile(MLContext mlContext, ITransformer model)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(_modelPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                mlContext.Model.Save(model, fs);
            Console.WriteLine("The model is saved to {0}", _modelPath);

        }

        public static void Predict(MLContext mlContext, ITransformer model)
        {
            var predictionFunction = model.MakePredictionFunction<NHLData, NHLPrediction>(mlContext);
            NHLData sampleTeam = new NHLData
            {
                Age = 29,
                Wins = 60,
                Losses = 22
            };
            var resultprediction = predictionFunction.Predict(sampleTeam);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("=============== Prediction Test of model with a single sample and test dataset ===============");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Age: {sampleTeam.Age} | Wins: {sampleTeam.Wins} | Losses: {sampleTeam.Losses} | Prediction: {(Convert.ToBoolean(resultprediction.Prediction) ? "Yes" : "No")} | Probability: {resultprediction.Probability} ");
            Console.WriteLine("=============== End of Predictions ===============");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static void PredictWithModelLoadedFromFile(MLContext mlContext)
        {
            IEnumerable<NHLData> teams = new[]
            {
                new NHLData
                {
                    Age = 29,
                    Wins = 30,
                    Losses = 52
                },
                new NHLData
                {
                    Age = 35,
                    Wins = 80,
                    Losses = 2
                }
            };
            ITransformer loadedModel;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(_modelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                loadedModel = mlContext.Model.Load(stream);
            }
            // Create prediction engine
            var nhlStreamingDataView = mlContext.CreateStreamingDataView(teams);
            var predictions = loadedModel.Transform(nhlStreamingDataView);

            // Use the model to predict whether comment data is toxic (1) or nice (0).
            var predictedResults = predictions.AsEnumerable<NHLPrediction>(mlContext, reuseRowObject: false);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("=============== Prediction Test of loaded model with a multiple samples ===============");
            var teamsAndPredictions = teams.Zip(predictedResults, (team, prediction) => (team, prediction));
            foreach (var item in teamsAndPredictions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Age: {item.team.Age} | Wins: {item.team.Wins} | Losses: {item.team.Losses} | Prediction: {(Convert.ToBoolean(item.prediction.Prediction) ? "Yes" : "No")} | Probability: {item.prediction.Probability} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("=============== End of predictions ===============");
        }
    }
}
```

*NHLData.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;

namespace MachineLearning2
{
    public class NHLData
    {
        [Column(ordinal: "0")]
        public float Age;
        [Column(ordinal: "1")]
        public float Wins;
        [Column(ordinal: "2")]
        public float Losses;
        [Column(ordinal: "3", name: "Label")]
        public float Playoffs;
    }

    public class NHLPrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public bool Prediction { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("Probability")]
        public float Probability { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*trainingNHL.txt* (columns: Age, Wins, Losses, Playoffs)

```
28.4,53,18,1
27.5,54,23,1
28,51,24,1
28.3,49,26,1
29.5,45,26,1
28.8,45,27,1
29.1,45,29,1
27.7,44,29,1
26.4,43,30,1
28.5,42,32,0
27,36,35,0
26.8,36,40,0
28,33,39,0
30.2,30,39,0
26.5,29,41,0
27.1,25,45,0
```

*testingNHL.txt* (columns: Age, Wins, Losses, Playoffs)

```
26.8,52,20,1
28.6,50,20,1
28.4,49,26,1
28.7,44,25,1
27.7,47,29,1
27.4,42,26,1
26.4,45,30,1
27.8,44,30,0
28.5,44,32,0
28.4,37,35,0
28.4,35,37,0
28.7,34,39,0
28.2,31,40,0
27.8,29,40,0
29.3,28,43,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is trainingNHL.txt the full dataset you are using or only a sample of it? I just tried training on it with FastTree and I see "Warning: 50 of the boosting iterations failed to grow a tree. This is commonly because the minimum documents in leaf hyperparameter was set too high for this dataset."

Given the parameters you set in FastTree, you will need more data to train a meaningful model. When I change `minDatapointsInLeafs` to 2, I am able to train a non-trivial model (although the results are still not extremely trustworthy due to the amount of data). You could also try using something like AveragedPerceptron or SDCA.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the full training data. I could expand the amount of data by grabbing previous seasons. I was trying to keep everything small since I was trying to figure out how to build my own model (not really using this model for anything) based on the tutorials in the docs. Thanks again for the help. I'll continue to look into these parameters on how to properly tune future models.

Comment: @TheBinaryCPA did you figured out the solution. I am also facing similar kind of issue.